# localhost is not loading files correctly

Tags: localhost

i am facing problem in loading css and js file from localhost in wamp
it always say that reload the page to get source.

```
[<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//assets/css/fullcalendar.css">
Reload the page to get source for: http://assets/css/fullcalendar.css
</link>
 <script src="//assets/js/jquery.min.js">
Reload the page to get source for: http://assets/js/jquery.min.js> </script>]
```

Comment: I don't think your issue will be reproducible from what you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing your ressources with a protocol-relative url, using

```
//assets/...
```

This is most likely wrong, as the server will try to access the file at either http://assets/... or https://assets/...

If your assets are located in a folder called 'assets' in the site root, simply use single slashes

```
href="/assets/..."
```

Comment: wamp uses Apache as server - and it can be configured in a lot of different ways

Comment: please tell me one of the way to configure it.

Comment: I can't. There are 100s of settings - and I have no way telling what would work.

Comment: What is the path to your 'assets' directory? try replacing the double '//' with single '/'

Comment: C:\wamp\www\fullcalendar\fullcalendar\assets

Comment: thanks for your answer but still it is not working                              [error:The requested URL /assets/css/fullcalendar.css was not found on this server]                                                                                                       I have written as you said [<link href="/assets/css/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>]

Comment: now when I try to load the same resource directly from browser using        [  http://127.0.0.1/fullcalendar/assets/css/fullcalendar.css]                           it's showing me css file ! Now I am confused how to solve this problem